# Didn't get half of the bounty

Tags: support, bounty

I answered a question which had a bounty on it and got a score of 5.

The question owner answered it and accepted his answer. The grace period is finished and the bounty and the bounty is not awarded to anyone. I know that the bounty cannot be awarded to the question owner. But why didn't I get the bounty if I was the person with the next highest score.

When reading **How is a bounty awarded?** part at Help Center it said:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted)

Question: [Where is the msdb database for standalone SSIS Servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437751/where-is-the-msdb-database-for-standalone-ssis-servers)

**Note:**
My answer was created before starting the bounty then deleted.. after awarding the bounty I undeleted my answer with an edited version, This is my answer timeline [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42475545/timeline)

Comment: the highest voted answer **created after the bounty started**?

Comment: your answer was posted before the bounty started as seen in the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42437751/timeline)

Comment: Undeleting a post doesn't magically update its creationdate. If your plan was to get the bounty you should have posted a new answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the question's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42437751/timeline) your answer was created before the bounty started. Therefore you fail the "answer created after the bounty started" test in the text you quoted.

Deleting and undeleting doesn't change the answer's creation date, if it did everyone would be incentivised to do that with their existing answers if they happened to be on a bountied question which would create pointless churn and would impede the desired effect of the bounty creator, i.e. the generation of **new** answers.

Comment: It was created then deleted.. after awarding the bounty i undelete my answer with an edited version

Comment: @Hadi That doesn't change anything.

Comment: It's still the same answer. Deleting and undeleting doesn't change the creation date.

Comment: Thx a lot for the information

Comment: What if they add new answer and copy the old answer into it?

Comment: @blackmiaool you get the bounty if your answer met the bounty requirements

Answer (score 3):

The highest voted answer **created after the bounty started**

**Exhibit A**

[image]

**Exhibit B**

[image]